# I want to view the latest updated page not the last viewed page each time I select a card redirecting it to it's product detail page instead of the la

Tags: reactjs, react-router

It's an old codebase I am refactoring, I have a page of product cards and every time a card is collected a history.push pushes with pathname to the card details page with the card id but when I go back from the browser and select another card I come back to the page with the old data and not the updated version. I am trying to update it with useEffect but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
const [ dataLoad, holdRender ] = useState(false);
  const [ product, setProduct ] = useState({});
  const [ currentProduct, setCurrentProduct ] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=> {
    (async () => {
      
      const productId = await props.getProduct(props.match.params.id);
      setCurrentProduct(productId);
    })();
return () => {
      if(!product){
        setProduct({})
      }
  }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const data = await props.security.product.data;
      setProduct(data);
    })();
    //if product.details is now available
    if(product?.details){
      //let go of render
      holdRender(true);
    }
     return () => {
//tried to reset here
        if(currentProduct !== 0){
          setCurrentProduct(0);
        }
    };
  }, [currentProduct, product]);

return(
    <div>
        {dataLoad !== false?
        <div>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Jumbotron id="productStatsCard">
                <div className="productStats">
                  <h2>{product? product.details_not_verified : <Loader/>}</h2>
                </div>
              </Jumbotron>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Jumbotron id="productStatsCard">
                <div className="productStats">
                  <h2>{product? product.details_verified: <Loader />}</h2>
                </div>
              </Jumbotron>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row className="mt-5">
            <Col sm={8}>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <div className="pdtTableContainer">
                    <div>
                      <Table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Product Id</th>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Product Type</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          {dataLoad && product?.details ? product?.details.map(detail => (
                            <tr key={product.id}>
                              <td>
                              {product.category}
                              </td>
                              <td>{product.id}</td>
                              <td>
                                  {product.product_title}
                              </td>
                              <td>{product.product_type}</td>
                            </tr>
                          )) : 'No products to display'}
                        </tbody>
                      </Table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>: <Loader/>}
      </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  security: state.security,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProduct })(productOverview);
```

Comment: Looks like you are just pushing the wrong id to history when redirecting. Do you see different product ids in url, when getting the same product on the detail page?

Comment: no, it was the correct id I was getting it right in the console after the render. It was as if it was not getting enough time to show itself. @Marat

Comment: I have already mentioned it below what helped me resolve the issue @DrewReese

Comment: I don't recall specifically what my comment was as it seems to have been deleted. Any mentions/comments below in the answer section are irrelevant to anyone asking for clarification in the above comments section. IIRC I asked specifically about the use of the `currentProduct` state that is updated but not really used and if the issue was that your code doesn't respond to `id` route param changes. I saw the answer below and thought it to be a bit naive so I wanted to try providing a more optimal answer if my suspicions on the issue could be confirmed.

Comment: the currentProduct is the id of the product card clicked, every time current id is changed i want the useEffect to run as you can see in the code above. @DrewReese

Comment: Which `useEffect` hook, there are two of them in your code snippet? I see that `currentProduct` is listed as a dependency in the second, but then isn't referenced, so it's not a true dependency. Is the gist that you want to `props.getProduct` with the current `id` route param and use that `productId` for something with `props.security.product.data`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I created a prev state to store the last value and added a condition to hold back data if it's equal to the current state.

```
const [ prev, setPrev ] = useState(0); //previous state
```

the condition as follows:

```
if(prev !== currentProduct){
        setCurrentProduct(props.match.params.id)
        const data = await props.security.product.data;
        setProduct(data);
      }
```